# inserting javascript in xslt not working in safari

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have a page that is pulling in an xml file uisng xslt.  I need to add some javascript to it and have managed to get it all working in IE and FF but Safari is a no no.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript" DEFER="true">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">  
<![CDATA[ 


     javascript here


]]>

</xsl:text>

</SCRIPT>
```

but I can;'t even get an alert in Safari?

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly are you applying the rendered XSLT into the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try these couple of things first.

1. See if the code is even being rendered on the page and if it is being rendered correctly i.e no encoding problems, no weird characters etc.
2. If it is being rendered, try putting alerts and try catches around that code to see where exactly it is failing.

That will help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: no I have tried these things and the js isn't even being rendered on the page! Safari doesn't really like xml

Comment: Your best bet is to try and isolate the problem. Remove stuff from the XSLT file until you are finally left with just script tag. Also if you have an online location where we can see this, I can try to debug.